# SQL Import/Export wizard not allowing Create Table #temp

Tags: sql, import, export, wizard

Through the Import/Export wizard (2008 R2) I'm trying to get data from a View and do some joins with it and put the data in a temp table then do a final select statement at the bottom.

But I keep getting a message saying that my first temp table definition is invalid.

Here's the def:

```
Create Table #CT (Code int, Col1 varchar(75), Col2 varchar(75), Col3 int) 
INSERT INTO #CT 
SELECT * 
FROM...
```

I know this is good because I can run it directly on the server without problems.

Is it that Imp/Exp wiz doesn't allow these kinds of queries, where there's complex statements?

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your SQL code, try adding [`set fmtonly off`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx).

In some circumstances, SQL Server tries to determine the metadata for a query without actually running the query... but, this doesn't play well with temp tables.  Adding `set fmtonly off` instructs it to actually execute the query to get the metadata.